# Error trying to run R in Sublime using REPL R on Mac "FileNotFoundError"

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimerepl

I am trying to run R from Sublime Text 3 on a Mac. I have followed various online instructions (http://tomschenkjr.net/blog/using-sublime-text-2-for-r/) but can't get it to work on my Mac.  I have configured the SublimeREPL settings for user as:

```
{
    "default_extend_env": {"PATH": "{PATH};~/Applications/R.app"},
    "show_transferred_text": true
}
```

and configured the Main.sublime-menu file to include the path to R.app as follows:

```
"cmd": {"linux": ["R", "--interactive", "--no-readline"],
        "osx": ["~/Applications/R.app", "--interactive", "--no-readline"],
        "windows": ["Rterm.exe", "--ess", "--encoding=$win_cmd_encoding"]},
```

I have tried other paths to no avail.  Any help?  Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: You need to use the full path. Sublime doesn't understand `~`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have [the latest R](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/) installed.

Then, try changing
`~/Applications/R.app` to `"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R"`.

So, it should look something like:

```
"osx": ["/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R", "--interactive", "--no-readline"],
```